# How to change which buttons appear in XFce4 logout screen?

Tags: xfce

I recall in older versions of XFce4, it was possible to access some advanced configuration tool. One of the features was the ability to customize the "log out" menu, e.g. hiding some of the buttons that aren't needed on a particular system, such as "Hibernate". Is there still a way to edit this?

Comment: google `xfce4 configuration hide hibernate button` ....     this is one of the hits... https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8723

Comment: That is what I was using before! The solution works for disabling Suspend and Hibernate, but the other buttons won't go away.

Comment: if your version of linux has a synaptic package manager, then you can check which files are installed for the Xfce desktop manager .... look for config files in the /etc directory

Comment: is hibernate still appearing? on my system it's not

Comment: The buttons for suspend and hibernate disappeared, but I can't find a solution for removing any other button.